# trying to execute a bash command in my apache server through my php script but getting error

Tags: php, bash, awk, exec

i have just started implemting bash commands into my php scripts the first few works fine now i am trying to do the following bash command in my php script

```
exec("awk -F: '{printf "www.example.com/2/tks.php?account=%s%%3A%s\n" ,$1, $2 }' < /opt/lampp/htdocs/$filename > /opt/lampp/htdocs/2.txt");
```

the error i am getting from my php script that worked fine before i put this in is

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'www' (T_STRING) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php on line 54
```

Comment: the exec command i posted above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape your double quotes in the string:

```
exec("awk -F: '{printf \"www.example.com/2/tasks.php?account=%s%%3A%s\\n\" ,$1, $2 }' < /opt/lampp/htdocs/$filename > /opt/lampp/htdocs/2.txt");
```

Comment: Then your shell command is wrong, but in PHP everything is right.

Comment: hmm this shell command works when using it in bash only change i amde was putting the $filname variable in any chance u can hep on this

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you've not escaped the double quotes for your `printf` statement inside the `exec` statement.

In it's current state, PHP treats `"awk -F: '{printf "` as the first part of the string since they're enclosed in double quotes. To tell PHP to ignore the other quotes, you can use a backslash.

Change it to:

```
exec("awk -F: '{printf \"www.example.com/2/tks.php?account=%s%%3A%s\n\" ,$1, $2 }' < /opt/lampp/htdocs/$filename > /opt/lampp/htdocs/2.txt");
```

Comment: that sort of worked only problem being it created the 2.txt file but had nothing inside what so ever

Comment: @AdiHelio It will create the file at the beginning of command execution, and if there's nothing to write, it won't be deleted.

Comment: This would solve the specific error. I don't have any more details to help you troubleshoot why the file was empty. Perhaps you should post a new question, with more details. :)

Comment: there is data to write it shold write the string above with added data that is created in $filename wich i know is working